# How to enable browser cache in AWS cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, .htaccess, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have configured my cloudfront distribution to use the managed cache policy, however all tools (like google pagespeed, cache checkers etc) are not detecting any caching.
Neither is the browser detecting any cache related header.

What am I missing here?

sample CDN url: https://cdn.thekiwi.app/images/skills/SubCategories/81/desktop_b/81.png
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood how Cloudfront cache works.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/controlling-the-cache-key.html

Cloudfront is the CDN that caches the resources on Cloudfront edge servers. Every time your users want to access your application's resources, either of the following 2 scenarios happens:

- Cache hit: the resource is cached in Cloudfront servers and returned to your users without requesting your app's origin server
- Cache miss: the resource is not cached and a request is sent to your app's origin server to retrieve. Then based on the cache policy you define in your Cloudfront distribution, the resource might or might not be cached in Cloudfront servers.

The cache policy you defined in your Cloudfront server tells Cloudfront when and how long to cache the resource.

Tools like Google pagespeed do not check for CDN cache, it checks for browser cache, which works based on the HTTP response headers such as [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control)

In order to set the Cache-Control value, you can either

(1) Write a Cloudfront functions to instruct Cloudfront to insert the header before returning responses to your users

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/example-function-add-cache-control-header.html

or

(2) Update your app's origin server to add the Cache-Control header for your resources.